# Putting three buttons side by side wont a large button on top

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble putting my simple image button webpage into action. I cannot align three buttons in the remaining space at the bottom of my webpage.

```css
       .fullwidth {

         width: 100%;

         height: 80%;

         margin-left: 0;

         margin-right: 0;

         padding-left: 0;

         padding-right: 0;

         display: block;

         text-align: center;

       }

       .tierwidth {

         width: 33.333333333333%;

         height: 20%;

         margin-left: 0;

         margin-right: 0;

         padding-left: 0;

         padding-right: 0;

         display: block;

         text-align: center;

       }

       html,

       body {

         height: 100%;

       }

       #footer {

         position: fixed;

         bottom: 0;

         width: 100%;

         height: 20%;

       }

       .btnContainer {

         float: left;

       }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>

<head>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1">
  <title>Excl Home</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.png" type="image/png">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="img/x-icon">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- FONTS BELOW -->


  <!-- FONTS STOP -->

</head>

<body>
  <a href="#" class="fullwidth"></a>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="btnContainer">
      <a href="#" class="tierwidth"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="btnContainer">
      <a href="#" class="tierwidth"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="btnContainer">
      <a href="#" class="tierwidth"></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br class="clearFloat">


  </head>

</html>
```

Comment: I tested your code with the snippet editor and didn't experience a problem. They align correctly for me -- can you include a picture to show your exact issue since we don't have access to the images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're doing is making a page with four buttons, you don't really need bootstrap. Since `.fullwidth` and `.tierwidth` share a lot of the same CSS properties, I moved those properties into the single rule. The differences get their own rule (i.e. `width` and `height`). If you make them float to the left, they will fill up as much space as possible before moving onto the next line. I added some color to make it easy to see what's what.

If you want the `.tierwidth` buttons to be in a fixed container the HTML will look a little different.

```css
.fullwidth,
.tierwidth {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  
  float:left;
}
.fullwidth {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  
  background-color: red;
}
.tierwidth {
  width: 33.333333333333%;
  height: 20%;

  background-color: blue;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="fullwidth"></a>
<a href="#" class="tierwidth"></a>
<a href="#" class="tierwidth"></a>
<a href="#" class="tierwidth"></a>
```

If you're looking to do something like this as part of a larger website and are using bootstrap elsewhere, you should probably look into the [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid), because the less custom CSS you use for layout the easier it will be to style and modify later.